# Accessing constant values from an Apache Velocity template?

Tags: java, velocity

Is it possible to access a constant value (i.e. a public static final variable defined in a Java class) from a Velocity template?

I would like to be able to write something like this:

```
#if ($a lt Long.MAX_VALUE)
```

but this is apparently not the right syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of ways.

1) You can put the values directly in the context.

2) You can use the [FieldMethodizer](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/FieldMethodizer.html) to make all public static fields in a class available.

3) You can use a custom Uberspect implementation that includes public static fields in the lookup order.

4) You can use the [FieldTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/FieldTool.html) from VelocityTools.

I recommend 1 for a few values, 2 for a few classes, 3 for lots of classes and values, and 4 if you are already using VelocityTools and would otherwise use 1 or 2.

Answer (score 6):

Velocity can only use anything it finds in its context, after e.g.

```
context.put("MaxLong", Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

You cannot use statics, or access static members of things in Velocity's context due to the way its lookup works (see Velocity's [Property lookup rules](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#propertylookuprules)). The best thing to do is add the value you want to check against explicitly in your context.

---

**Edit October 6** on second sight, it seems to be possible to access static members. See the velocity [Developer guide - Support for "Static Classes"](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#supportforstaticclasses) for more information. I have not tried this out, though.

Comment: The support for Static classes, does not extend to static fields, just static methods.  Also, it is only in the latest version 1.6-beta1.